# Stop ion-change firing until values loaded from storage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

On my settings page I have several `ion-toggle`'s. I have an `onChange` method that updates local storage when they are toggled. Fairly standard stuff, when the page is loaded I check the storage for the existing values and then map them to the toggle's using `ngModel`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="alertTitle"><p>Enable Notifications</p></td>
        <td><ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notificationsEnabled" (ionChange)="toggleAlert('NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED')"></ion-toggle></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="alertTitle"><p>Job Received</p></td>
        <td><ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="jobReceived" (ionChange)="toggleAlert('JOB_RECEIVED')"></ion-toggle></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="alertTitle"><p>Document Created</p></td>
        <td><ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="documentCreated" (ionChange)="toggleAlert('DOCUMENT_CREATED')"></ion-toggle></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" class="alertTitle"><p>Document Rejected</p></td>
        <td><ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="documentRejected" (ionChange)="toggleAlert('DOCUMENT_REJECTED')"></ion-toggle></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Toggle function:

```
allAlertsLoaded(): boolean {
  return this.notificationsEnabledLoaded && this.jobReceivedLoaded && this.documentCreatedLoaded && this.documentRejectedLoaded;
}

toggle(alertConst: string) {
  if (!this.allAlertsLoaded()) {
    return;
  }

  this.storage.get(alertConst).then(res => {
    if (res) {
      this.storage.set(alertConst, false);
      return;
    }
    this.storage.set(alertConst, true);
  });
}
```

Function called  in `ngOnInit` to load the existing values:

```
loadToggles() {
  this.storage.get(NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED).then(res => {
    this.notificationsEnabled = res;
    this.notificationsEnabledLoaded = true;
  });
  this.storage.get(JOB_RECEIVED).then(res => {
    this.jobReceived = res;
    this.jobReceivedLoaded = true;
  });
  this.storage.get(DOCUMENT_CREATED).then(res => {
    this.documentCreated = res;
    this.documentCreatedLoaded = true;
  });
  this.storage.get(DOCUMENT_REJECTED).then(res => {
    this.documentRejected = res;
    this.documentRejectedLoaded = true;
  });
}
```

Problem: When the page loads, because the `stoage.get` is async the toggle values are default to `false` then when they are loaded it triggers `toggle()` as they are changed. I need the toggle function not to run until they are all loaded.

My solution: I added a `Loaded` variable for each of the toggles that gets set to `true` once they are loaded. I then check all are loaded before allowing `toggle()` to run.

This fixed the first 3 toggles but the last one still toggles off on page load.

Any other solutions or my bug would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options you can consider:

**a) Code suitably and take advantage of fast js async engine (Simple & Preferred)**

```
 <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="notificationsEnabled" (ionChange)="toggle('NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED', notificationsEnabled)"></ion-toggle>

toggle(alertConst: string, value: boolean) {
 this.storage.set(alertConst, value);
}
```

**b) Use async/await for force wait until Promise is resolved**

> > You can find more reference [here](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/async-await-in-typescript-tutorial/) on implementation

**c) Use routing resolve guard to complete before page load**

> > You can find more reference [here](https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/) on implementation